# Derive an expression for the inverse of $\textrm{exp}(A)=I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse

Let $\textrm{exp}:M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the function on the space of $2\times2$ matrices defined by

$\textrm{exp}(A)=I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\dots$.

Derive an expression for the inverse of exp.

I gather that the inverse ought to resemble some form of $\ln{x}$, so the solution ought to look like some Taylor expansion of this function in terms of matrices. Proving this rigorously is giving me trouble though.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can use the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) or just cheat and use the taylor series for the logarithm $\ln(1+x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}$

Comment: Are you looking for the inverse of $\exp$ (which would be a function) or are you looking for the inverse of $\exp{A}$ (which would be a matrix)? You title asks for the latter but the body asks for the former.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that $e^{A+B}=e^{A}e^{B}$, if $AB=BA$.
Hence, for $B=-A$ it is clear that the inverse of $e^{A}$ is $e^{-A}$.
I hope now that you can easily calculate what you are asking, through substitution.

Comment: I   guess we are looking for the inverse function $g = f^{-1}$, i.e. given a matrix $A$, we require $A = g(f(A))$ and $f(A) = \exp A$.  You are giving the "inverse" $1/f(A)$.

Comment: @Jess has given a matrix $ B = exp(A) $ and given his question, I understand that he asks for its inverse $B^{-1}$. But I guess he could clarify a bit more.

Comment: Yes - @Will R (see his comment above) has the same question. But reading the OPs question: "I gather that the inverse ought to resemble some form of ln x" suggests to me that we are asked to look for $g(B)=f^{-1} (B) = A$, where particularly we either find some functional representation $g(B)$, or a series representation.

Answer (score 0):

Let a matrix $B = f(A) = \exp A$, then the inverse function can be understood as a function of a matrix $B$, namely $g(B) = f^{-1}(B) = A$. The required function $g(B)$ can be understood as the "matrix logarithm" as generalization of the scalar logarithm. Details on when the matrix logarithm exists and how its series representation looks like can e.g. be found [here (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix).